# Inappbrowser not loading

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

Im using Phonegap 2.9.0 in ios, i have gone through the tutorial for [inappbrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) .and i have tried the following to in my application

**App.js Calling method**

```
indexpnl.element.on({
        tap: function (e) {
            var el = Ext.get(e.target);
            var bval = el.getId();
     if (bval == "btnfacebook") {
              //   onDeviceReady()//using this application screen its self loading the site view not in inappbrowser
              document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);//here nothing happening
            }
        }
    });
```

**jsfunction.js Method**

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    var ref = window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}
```

And i have include the plug in config.xml

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

When i call using the above method nothing happens.When i call On onDeviceReady() the site is loading in application itslef but not in the inapp browser.What wrong with my code

Comment: is the tap fired? try console.log('tap') to check the calllback

Comment: Have you added the .m and .h files for the plugin to your Xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno but have you checked you have a

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

in your script as in

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using

Leaving it out can produce those kind of errors